# How to invert image's colors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, pixel

When I run the program the image shows up and I need to invert the RBG values of each pixel. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score -1):

can't you just use CSS (filter:invert(100%);)?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=invert(100%25)